# A question about BGP Confederations

Tags: untagged

With BGP Confederations, why are the Confederation ASNs prepended to the AS Path field? From what I've read, they are not used when determining the shortest path to any destinations.

I could assume that this works as a Loop Prevention mechanism so that BGP packets aren't going back and forth between the Confederations they've already passed, but there's already a path attribute called AS_CONFED_SEQ which is an ordered list of confederation ASNs the UPDATE packet traversed through.

[image]

So what would be the point of prepending the Confederation ASNs to the AS Path Field? Is there really any use to it?

Thank you in advance for your help.

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confederation's are basically using EBGP behavior to solve IBGP problems (i.e. full mesh requirements). So with that you have to consider two scenarios:

1. The case where a route advertisement traverses an AS that ***is** part of the confederation* (i.e. a known sub-AS).

In this case let's say you have a Confederation AS of 65500 and two sub-ASes 65401 and 65402. If a route is exchanged between 65401 and 65402 then typical EBGP rules will apply so that loops can be prevented. So, 65401 will prepend it's sub-AS when advertising the route to 65402.

2. The case where a route advertisement traverses an AS that ***is not** part of the confederation*.

Let's add another EBGP speaker that is not part of the Confederation, let's say it's Amazon with AS 16509 that is peered with a node in sub-AS 65401. When 65401 advertises routes to 16509 it will prepend the Confederation AS of 65500 as 16509 because it is not part of the confederation and therefore has no understanding of it. This will allow 16509 to properly handle loop prevention on their end.